# How to create Stripe elements postal code that accepts UK postcodes?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, postal-code

I'm creating a payment form with separate Stripe Elements:

```js
var stripe = Stripe(...);
var elements = stripe.elements();
...
var postalCode = elements.create('postalCode');
postalCode.mount('#postalCode');
```

This creates a field that accepts only digits. However, the UK's post codes contain letter as well. How do I allow these too? I want the user to be able to input pretty much any possible post code in the world.

Comment: According to Stripe's documentation at https://stripe.com/docs/elements/reference#postal-code-formatting  "...the postal code field validation reflects whether that country uses numeric or alphanumeric-formatted postal codes, or if the country uses postal codes at all. For instance, if a U.S. card is entered, the postal code field only accepts a five-digit numeric value. If it’s a UK card, an alphanumeric value can be provided instead."

Comment: @alfredo No idea how I managed to miss that. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Sometimes another pair of eyes helps. I'm glad my pair of eyes helped you.

Comment: The link in @alfredo's comment is broken. Here is the new link https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/postal_code_formatting

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the form dynamically adjusts based on the card you enter, since the card indicates its country. However, it doesn't seem to validate effectively. I was able to create a valid test order with invalid UK postcode.

[Stripe has test card numbers for many countries](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#international-cards). Try entering them into your Elements forms.

Form when user types Stripe's generic (US) test Visa card shows "ZIP" (it shows ZIP when empty too):

[image: Form with Stripe's generic (US) Visa card]

The same form when user types in Stripe's test UK Visa card changes to showing "Postcode" during typing:

[image: Form with Stripe's UK test card]

Comment: Tried a few if I recall correctly. Please share data if it works now, maybe Stripe fixed it since.

Comment: We're getting reports of postcodes failing validation but when we try with the same postcodes it works. Might be something else at play.

Comment: @AdrianLynch did you solve the issue?  Getting the same reports here, even tested with our user's postcode with test cards and it seems fine. Investigating further....

Comment: @RobB - We've added logging to gather more details from the customer interaction. Since adding the logging, it hasn't been happened!